# Mongo driver with @Testcontainers, throws exceptions after tests run successfully

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I'm setting up integration tests in a sample spring boot kotlin project, using testcontainers:mongodb.

I've set up a MongoDBContaine, and everything works as expected - the app connects to the mongodb and tests with repositories (e.g. save, delete) work perfectly fine, but I've noticed that after the tests ran (successfully) mongodb.driver throws an exception in the end - would seem like the container isn't being gracefully closed/stopped - is that possible?

Example of how I start the container

```
companion object {
        @Container
        var mongoDBContainer = MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.4.2")

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun setProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri") { mongoDBContainer.replicaSetUrl }
        }
    }
```

Test method

```
@Test fun someTest() {
   autowiredRepository.save(document)
   ...
   ...
}
```

As for the running class, I'm simply using the @Testcontainers annotation on top of it with @SpringBootTest, nothing else.

The exception I'm getting in the end is

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:647) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:512) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:355) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receive(InternalStreamConnection.java:315) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:215) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Same for me, did you find the solution yet??

Comment: nope, didnt find any solution

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue and solved it by removing the annotation `@Container` from my container and starting it manually as a Singleton.
The reason is that `@Container` was starting multiple containers. The first one was being successfully used by the tests and the other ones were throwing the `com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream` exception.

Replacing this:

```java
    @Testcontainers  
    @DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)  
    class UserRepositoryTest {  
    
        @Container  
        static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:5.0.10");  
    
        @DynamicPropertySource  
        static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {  
            registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDBContainer::getReplicaSetUrl);  
        }
    }
```

with this

```java
    @Testcontainers  
    @DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)  
    class UserRepositoryTest {  
    
        static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:5.0.13");
    
        static {
            mongoDBContainer.start();
        }
    
        @DynamicPropertySource  
        static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {  
            registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDBContainer::getReplicaSetUrl);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This workaround still works on SpringBoot 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to exclude the default mongoEmbedded which is provided by spring?

I don't know in Kotlin but in Java it's something like that:

```
@Testcontainers  
@DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)  
class UserRepositoryTest {  

    @Container  
    static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:5.0.10");  

    @DynamicPropertySource  
    static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {  
        registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDBContainer::getReplicaSetUrl);  
    }
}
```